# Collapse/mean data in Matlab with respect to a different set of data

Tags: matlab, time, binning

I have two sets of data, but the sets have a different sizes. 
Each set contains the measurements itself (MeasA and MeasB, both double) and the time point (TimeA and TimeB, datenum or julian date) when the measuring happened.

Now I want to match the smaller data set to the bigger one, and to do this, I want to mean the data points of the bigger set around the data resp. time points of the smaller set, to finally do some correlation analysis.

Edit:
Small Example how the data would look like:

```
MeasA = [2.7694 -1.3499 3.0349 0.7254 -0.0631];
TimeA = [0.2 0.4 0.7 0.8 1.3];

MeasB = [0.7147 -0.2050 -0.1241 1.4897 1.4090 1.4172 0.6715 -1.2075 0.7172 1.6302];
TimeB = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.6 0.65 0.68 0.73 0.85 1.2 1.4];
```

And now I want to collapse MeasB and TimeB so that I get the mean of the measurement close to the timepoints in TimeA, so for example TimeB should look like this:

```
TimeB = [mean([0.1 0.2]) mean([0.3 0.6]) mean([0.65 0.68 0.73]) mean([0.85]) mean([1.2 1.4])]
TimeB = [0.15 0.4 0.69 0.85 1.3]
```

And then collapse MeasB like this too:

```
MeasB = [mean([0.7147 -0.2050]) mean([-0.1241 1.4897]) mean([1.4090 1.4172 0.6715]) mean([-1.2075]) mean([0.7172 1.6302])];
MeasB = [0.2549 0.6828 1.1659 -1.2075 1.1737]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`interp1`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) is your friend.

You can get a new set of measurement for your set `B`, at the same time than set `A` by using:

```
newMeasB = interp1( TimeB , MeasB , TimeA ) ;
```

The first 2 parameters are your original Time and Measurements of the set you want to re interpolate, the last parameter is the new x axis (time in your example) on which you want the interpolated values to be calculated.

This way you do not end up with different sets of time between your 2 sets of measurements, you can compare them point by point.

Check the documentation of [`interp1`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) for more explanations and for options about the interpolation or any potential extrapolation.

---

*edit:*
Matlab doc used to have a great illustration of the function but I can't find it online so here goes:
[image: Matlab Interp1]

So with the `linear` method, if the value is interpolated exactly between 2 points, the function will return the exact mean. If the interpolation is done closer to one point than another, the value returned will be proportionally closer to the value of the closest point.

The `NaN` can appear on the sides (beginning or end of returned vector) if the `TimeA` was not completely overlapped by `timeB`. The function cannot "interpolate" because there is no anchor point. However, the different options of `interp1` allow you to "extrapolate" outside of the input range, or to assign another default value instead of the NaNs.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the closest to what I need. If I want it to calculate the closest to a mean, would it be the linear-Method?

Comment: And another question, this function gives me a few NaNs, is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @user3199134, I edited the post to answer your comments