# Convert matlab interp1 to python

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation

I have the following line of code in matlab;

```
for frame = 1:Param.numframes
     bscan(:,:,frame,:) = interp1(bscan(:,:,frame,:), Param.resample, 'linear');
```

In matlab:

- bscan is a matrix of shape (1024, 895, 400, 4)
- Param.resample is a matrix of shape (1024, 1)

In python:

- bscan is a numpy array of shape (1024, 895, 400, 4)
- resample is a tuple with 1024 values in it

How can I translate this matlab code into python so that it produces the same output?

I have tried a variety of different approaches using both numpy and scipy but they always produce different results to what matlab produces. I have checked that all the values are the same between the two scripts until this point, I have included my current attempt below

```
    for ch in range(4):
        interp = interp1d(np.arange(bscan_dims[0]),
                                          bscan[:, :, frame, ch],
                                          axis=0,
                                          kind='linear',
                                          fill_value='extrapolate')(np.array(resampling_table).reshape(1024, 1))
        bscan[:, :, frame, ch] = interp.reshape(1024, 895)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting MATLAB's interp1 to Python interp1d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867103/converting-matlabs-interp1-to-python-interp1d)

Comment: No, I have seen that answer before and tried similar approaches but I just cant seem to get it to work

Comment: Then I suggest you post your Python code along with sample inputs, desired outputs and the incorrect output from your code.

Comment: I have added my code, cant really add outputs as they are very large arrays of seemingly random values